# getting last date not all in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I am getting date from web services. when I use the below code I ll get last row's object's date not all object's date. I want, if the date is earlier then current date then text in row will become green otherwise it'll become red.

```
NSDate *today =[NSDate date];
        NSComparisonResult result;

    NSString *abc = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",[_currentItemValue objectForKey:@"EndDate" ]];

    NSDateFormatter* df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];

    NSDate *a = [df dateFromString:abc];
    result =[today compare:a];

    if(result == NSOrderedDescending)
       {
           [cell.btn_policy_no setTitleColor:[UIColor greenColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
       }
```

Comment: you this code in cellForRowIndexPath method??

Answer (score 0):

Probably because of `[_currentItemValue objectForKey:@"EndDate" ]` this line, it will give always one object and when your table view will visible last row code executed and hence it's showing last row.If you need to get each row object.You need to get each different object for each row.